# Unable to List All SharePoint Online Lists Using SharePoint SPFX Framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework

I'm new to SharePoint SPFX development. As I am new to SharePoint SPFx, I was trying the below Microsoft Official Tutorial Connect your client-side web part to SharePoint (Hello World part 2) .

I successfully completed Part 01 of the tutorial series, Build your first SharePoint client-side web part (Hello World part 1)

When I'm following Part 02 I got stuck at the below 2 methods

01

private _renderListAsync(): void {

```
this._getListData()

  .then((response) => {

    this._renderList(response.value);

  })

  .catch(() => {});
```

}

The error is in line 4 (response.value), which is 'Argument of type 'ISPLists[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ISPList[]'.

Type 'ISPLists' is missing the following properties from type 'ISPList': Title, Idts(2345)'

Also in the same method line 6 (.catch(() => {});), which is 'Unexpected empty arrow function.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function'

02

private _getListData(): Promise {

```
return this.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists?$filter=Hidden eq false`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)

  .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {

    return response.json();

  })

  .catch(() => {});
```

}

The error is in line 6 (.catch(() => {});), which is Unexpected empty arrow function.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function

I tried many threads but didn't get an answer.

I'm using SharePoint Online, NodeJs 16.20.0, NPM 8.19.4 without using any front-end framework like React or Angular.

Please refer to the below link for the source code for the solution.

Source code - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RccnNmjIDdqeOvUxg-cnG-byxVwuhNe8?usp=sharing

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Best regards,

ChiranthakaJ

Comment: I found the answer in the below thread. [enter link description here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306907/spfx-retrieve-lists-using-sharepoint-rest-api/312627#312627)